# Flash/ActionScript2.0: How to loop music until end of scene?

Tags: flash, loops, actionscript, actionscript-2

I created a music loop but the problem is, when i put it into flash, the music continues even after the scene finishes, and if i wait for the Music to end, it wont loop.

How do I make music in flash loop and end at the end of the scene?

Im using actionscript2.0 on flash cs6

Answer (score 0):

To stop a sound or loop, call the stop metod - [Sound.stop()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7bba.html).

```
var my_sound:Sound = new Sound(); 
my_sound.loadSound("song1.mp3", true); 

stop_btn.onRelease = function() { 
    trace("sound stopped"); 
    my_sound.stop(); 
}; 

play_btn.onRelease = function() { 
    trace("sound started"); 
    my_sound.start(0, 10); // Loop sound 10 times
};
```

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the answer, but im using actionscript2 which mean i can apply actions directly on objects/buttons on the stage.